# Kivy - Accessing id of widget outside of the root class

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I wish to retrieve the id of a widget in order to access its `text` attribute, in a widget class *outside* of the root class. I understand in order to affect or retrieve items with an id from kv-lang, the following syntax may be used:

```
self.ids.some_id.some_attribute = new_value
```

This works perfectly fine when used in the root class, as access is available to all its children. However in a widget class, the class only refers to the widget declared, so any ids outside of it are out of scope.

```
<Root>:
    ...
        SomeButton:
           ...
        TextInput:
            id: some_id
```

What doesn't work:

```
class SomeButton(Button):
    def on_press(self):
        print(self.ids.some_id.text)
```

As I mentioned, this is understandable. But I don't know then what is used in this instance. Any assistance would be appreciated :)

Comment: you can provide a [mcve], your code is not complete so I will have to patch it and therefore assume many things that do not reproduce its error, besides investing unnecessary time.

Comment: You want to access the `ids` declared under your `SomeButton`.
Instead you should access the `ids` of the parent of `SomeButton`.

Comment: @GáborFekete rather I want to access the id declared under textinput within the somebutton class

Comment: @eyllanesc Actually there is nothing to reproduce. I merely ask how I can access an id outside of the scope of a certain widget class

Comment: @bobbyyoung In your example code TextInput is a sibling of SomeButton. SomeButton doesn't have any TextInput so there will be no id for one. But you can access it by using `self.parent.ids['some_id'].text` from SomeButton.

Comment: @bobbyyoung That answer depends on the context, and for this it is necessary that you provide a [mcve], if you do not give a context then your question is too broad making it off-topic for SO. read [ask]

Comment: @GáborFekete  that would indeed make sense. Unfortunately I get a `KeyError: 'some_id'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new in kivy but i think TextInput is not a child widget of a SomeButton but you are trying to access it from Button anyway. That's your problem.

Try `self.parent.ids.some_id.text`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that ids are local to the rule, not to the widget.

here your rule is declared for `<Root>`, so to access it you have to use a reference to this widget, not to the button.

If you want to give a reference to some_id to button, you can add a property to your button.

```
class SomeButton(Button):
    target = ObjectProperty()
    def on_press(self):
        print self.target.text
```

and link them together in kv.

```
<Root>:
...
    SomeButton:
        target: some_id

    TextInput:
        id: some_id
```